# how to store text containing escape sequences in ms access

Tags: ms-access

When i try to store text containing 'C' code in MS ACCESS table (programatically). It replaces escape sequences ('\n', '\t') with some question-mark symbol.

Example :

code to store :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("\n\n\t Hi there...");
  return 0;
}
```

When i see MS-Access table for above inserted code it shows every newline and '\t' character replaced with a '?' kind of symbol.

My question "is there any other data type for MS-Access filed which stores code as it is without replacing escape sequences with some symbol?"
and
"Is 'raw' data type present in other DBMS like MYSQL will do my job?  "

This is how it shows in access-07 :

[image: This is how it shows question mark symbols]

Comment: I've been working with Access since '94, and have never seen this, nor did I when I tested it just now. You'll have to provide more details like which version of Access are you using, how exactly are you storing the text, and how exactly are you viewing the text where you see the ? mark.

Comment: I agree - makes little sense. Perahps the column (memo) is set as rich text, and that is messing this up. The other possible is you have autocorrect turned on. That will "replace" character sequences, but not when writing to a table via code.

Comment: I'm using MS-ACESS 2007 with no autocorrect on, in design view of table i have selected 'Text' as data-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the line breaks in your source text are not the Windows-standard CRLF (carriage return, line feed).  Find out the character codes of those mystery characters.

Using the procedure below, I can feed it a text string, and it will list the code of each character.  Here is an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
AsciiValues "a" & vbcrlf & "b"
position      Asc           AscW
 1             97            97 
 2             13            13 
 3             10            10 
 4             98            98
```

If I want to examine the value stored in a table text field, I can use `DLookup` to fetch that value and feed it to the function.

```vb
AsciiValues DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id=1")
position      Asc           AscW
 1             108           108 
 2             105           105 
 3             110           110 
 4             101           101 
 5             32            32
```

Once you determine the codes of the problem characters, you can execute an `UPDATE` statement to replace the problem character codes with suitable alternatives.

```vb
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourField = Replace(YourField, Chr(x), Chr(y));
```

And this is the procedure ...

```vb
Public Sub AsciiValues(ByVal pInput As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngSize As Long
    lngSize = Len(pInput)
    Debug.Print "position", "Asc", "AscW"
    For i = 1 To lngSize
        Debug.Print i, Asc(Mid(pInput, i, 1)), AscW(Mid(pInput, i, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's probably that you're lacking the whole newline. A newline in Access consists of a  Carriage Return (ASCII 13) **AND** a Line Feed (ASCII 10). This is abbreviated as CRLF. You probably only have one or the other, but not both.

Use HansUp's AsciiValues procedure to take a look.